# Are strings null terminated automatically by the compiler in C?

Tags: c, initialization, declaration, c-strings, string-literals

```
char *a = "string one";
char b[] = "string two";
char c[] = {'s','t','3'};
```

Are any of the above string examples `null` terminated with `\0` automatically?
I'm sure the last example isn't.

Answer (score 2):

String literals are character arrays containing sequences of characters ended with the terminating zero character `'\0'`. For example this string literal `"string one"` has the type `char[11]` and can be imagined like

```
char string_literal[] = { 's', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g', ' ', 'o', 'n', 'e', '\0' };
```

In this declaration

```
char *a = "string one";
```

the pointer `a` is initialized by the address of the first character of the string literal `"string one"`.

In this declaration the array `b` is initialized by the elements of the string literal `"string two"` including its terminating zero character and has the type `char[11]`.

```
char b[] = "string two";
```

This declaration is equivalent to

```
char b[] = { 's', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g', ' ', 't', 'w', 'o', '\0' };
```

In this declaration

```
char c[] = {'s','t','3'};
```

that is equivalent to

```
char c[3] = "st3"; // non valid in C++ but valid in C
```

the array `c` having the type `char[3]` does not contain a string because neither its element is the terminating zero character.

Comment: Should maybe mention `char d[3] = "st3";` which is valid but gives d the same type and value as your c, i.e. not a string.

Comment: thank you, so `a and b` are null terminated but `c` ins't.

Comment: @zwol I think it's an Undefined Behaviour, because if you put something into ```double quotes``` like this ```char d[3] = "st3";```, it means a string and to show the end of the string you must add \0 at the end but in your case there's no space for \0 as the sizeof char d[] is 3.

Comment: @Josh Strictly speaking a is not null terminated. It is a pointer. But the pointer string literal is null terminated. b is indeed null terminated because it is an array, containing a string.

Comment: @Lucas There's a special case in the standard for my example. It's well-defined, but d winds up not being a string. (Normally, supplying more initializer elements than will fit in the declared space is a constraint violation.)